# Looking up a value in every column except one and return a value from the last column using r

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to r and are having some troubles with a code.

I have a data frame looking like this:
[image: The data frame i'm using]

For every column i want to look up the value 1982Q4 and return the corresponding value from the column `datadate`. I have tried using the code:

```
Constituents_list <- colnames(datacqtr)
Constituents_list <- Constituents_list[-1]
Results <- 0
for(i in Constituents_list) {
Results <- cbind(Results, na.omit(with(datacqtr,datadate[Constituents_list== "1982Q4"])))
}
```

But it does not work. I can succesfully get one value if I write the column name myself using the code

```
Results <- cbind(Results, na.omit(with(datacqtr,datadate[`6307`== "1982Q4"])))
```

But since I have over 3000 columns, that's not really an option.

I hope someone is able to help, and thanks in advance!

Best regards
Rasmus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try whether this might work:

```
apply(datacqtr[,-1], 2, function(x) datacqtr$datadate[grepl("1982Q4",x)])
```

Comment: Great answer! This is more elegant than using a for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simulating a small dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  datadate=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
  A=c('1982Q4', NA, NA, NA),
  B=c(NA, '1982Q4', NA, NA),
  C=c(NA, NA, '1982Q4', NA),
  D=c(NA, NA, NA, '1982Q4')
)
```

The corresponding value for column `A` in `datadate` column will be `a`, and so on.

Now you can use apply (in R, avoid using `for` loops):

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) df$datadate[which(x=='1982Q4')])
```

The output:

```
$A
[1] a
Levels: a b c d

$B
[1] b
Levels: a b c d

$C
[1] c
Levels: a b c d

$D
[1] d
Levels: a b c d
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the fastest methods is to use the first column as a lookup table, and then use `max.col` to pull off the desired index for each column.

In the example provided by @thebiro, you would do

```
df$datadate[max.col(df[-1] == "1982Q4" & !is.na(df[-1]))]
[1] a b c d
Levels: a b c d
```

Here, you have to check for the value with `==` and make sure that the value is not NA.